# How to resolve this error while deploying React Python app on Azure Container Apps?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, dockerfile, azure-container-apps

I was able to deploy my code and image successfully on Google Cloud Run. But the same setup is resulting in error while deploying on Azure Container Apps. Would you please suggest what could be cause and how it can be fixed?
I am executing the command:

```
az containerapp up
```

Here is the error that I receive:

```
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './node_modules\\@babel\\plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator\\node_modules\\@babel\\helper-function-name\\node_modules\\@babel\\types\\lib\\builders\\flow\\createTypeAnnotationBasedOnTypeof.js'
```

Here is my dockerfile content:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build-step
WORKDIR app/
# ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
# COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
# COPY package.json yarn.lock tsconfig.json ./
# COPY src/ ./src
# COPY public/ ./public
COPY . ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

# Build step #2: build the API with the client as static files
FROM python:3.11.2-bullseye

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

WORKDIR app/
COPY --from=build-step app/build ./build

RUN mkdir ./api
COPY api/ ./api
RUN pip3 install -U pip && pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r ./api/requirements.txt

ENV QUART_ENV $QUART_ENV

# EXPOSE $PORT
WORKDIR /app/api
# CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:flask_app
CMD exec hypercorn --bind :$PORT main:quart_app
```

Here is my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/moment": "^2.15.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@formkit/auto-animate": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player": "^3.4.9",
    "@mui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.54",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.19",
    "@types/superagent": "^4.1.15",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.4",
    "firebase": "^9.9.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "query-string": "^7.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.0.3",
    "react-ga4": "^1.4.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.25.3",
    "react-iframe": "^1.8.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "underscore": "^1.13.2",
    "universalify": "^2.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },

"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `**/node_modules/` to your `.dockerignore` file. (or create one at the root of your repo if you don't have one)

You're hitting a Windows `MAXPATH` issue see this for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation

You can also try enabling Long Paths if you have >= Windows 10, Version 1607 see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later

Comment: I am using the node alpine Linux image within Dockerfile. Does it still require me to take care of Windows MAXPATH related issue? Apparently, what is also confusing is that it is showing [WinError 3], which suggests that somehow the Windows image is being built.

Comment: The docker client running on Windows is trying to copy all files to the docker image you're building, and it's failing to copy that file because its path is too long on the Windows side.

Comment: Why does it happen even if I have added nice modules in docker invite file?